# Задать значение input.files

Tags: jquery, form, input, fileupload, jquery-file-upload

Величайшие умы планеты, подскажите пожалуйста как можно задать значение методу files для input.
История такова, что для загрузки фотографий на [тестовый сайт](http://workout.korets.in.ua/xbolt/post2.html) я имею:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="uploadImg" name="tmp" value="Фотографії" multiple />
```

Который формирует превью фотографий *(для пользователя)* в такой схеме:

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang.jpg" data-rank="1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang2.jpg" data-rank="2" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

И input'ы *(для отправки на серв)* в такой:

```html
<input type="file" name="photos" data-rank="1" />
<input type="file" name="photos" data-rank="2" />
```

На англ. версии stackoverflow есть ["такой же"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515232/how-to-set-file-input-value-when-dropping-file-on-page) вопрос с описанием его работы.
Изучив статью на MSDN, мне не удалось ни коим образом решить это задание.
Кто имел подобный опыт с изменением значение input.files ?!

Собственно весь код моих творений:

```js
function ShowFile(e) {
  var files = e.target.files;
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) continue;
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        $('#list').append('<li><img src="' +e.target.result+ '" /></li>').css('background-image', 'none');
        $('#photoInputs').append('<input type="file" name="photos" />');
        $('#photoInputs input[name="photos"]').last().files = theFile; // underfined
      };
    })(f);        
    fr.readAsDataURL(f)
  }
}
```

Comment: А чего вы пытаетесь достичь?

Comment: Задать значение динамически созданным input'ам

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите автоматизированно утянуть файлы с компьютера пользователя? Так не полн

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я хочу разбить файлы из input'a #uploadImg со свойством multiply на несколько input'ов. Методу .files которых, задать соответствующее значение из #uploadImg

Comment: На примере загрузки файлов на OLX

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Вы как форму собираетесь отправлять? Ajax-ом?

Comment: @zhurof обычная отправка через submit (без Ajax)

Comment: @Igor Дяка за корректное направление. Действительно "Проблема Молотка " XY в моем случае присутствует.

Comment: @KobetsMatviy Попробуйте объяснить, зачем Вам это нужно. Пока это непонятно.

Comment: @Igor Имеется сайт б\у запчастей. На нем есть "добавление объявлений". На странице добавления есть поле выбора фото. Элемент input имеет свойство multiply для загрузки нескольких фото, которые как хотелось бы разбивались на несколько input'ов для удаления / редактирования / предпросмотра перед отправкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент изменил подход **выбора** и **загрузки файлов** на сайт.
Раньше можно было выбрать несколько файлов *(свойство multiply)*, однако из-за неизвестности, как их разбить в дальнейшем, переработал на загрузку по одному файлу в уже статические input'ы.
Результат работы можете посмотреть все на той же [тестовой версии](http://workout.korets.in.ua/xbolt/post.html).
Но вопрос остаеться в силе, так как выбирать файлы "по одному", а не "все сразу" при возможности что человек хочет добавить 20 объявлений - дело не самое радужное.

Код имеет такой вид:

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icons"></span>
      <label>
        <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang.jpg" />
        <input type="file" name="photos" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="delPhotos" />
      </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icons"></span>
      <label>
        <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang7.jpg" />
        <input type="file" name="photos" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="delPhotos" />
      </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```